# What is the dimension of the polar fractal $\mathrm{r=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sgn(sec(n\theta))}{n}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, fractal-analysis

Here is what the fractal looks like on desmos; you can change the width of the function for more detail [**desmos fractal**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dllq67sias) This is the

> [inspiration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859810/fractal-dimension-of-the-function-fx-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mathrmsign-l)

for the question. I will use this [inverse tangent generalization](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/05/), [polar coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) and the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). Note that I cannot solve for y in closed form and that $\mathrm{k\Bbb Z=kZ,Z\in\Bbb Z}$. We would like to find out a [fractal dimension](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$:
$$\mathrm{r=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sgn(sec(n\theta))}{n}\implies \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sgn\left(sec\left(n\,tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)+kn\Bbb Z\right)\right)}{n}\implies y=\pm\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sgn\left(sec\left(n\,tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)+kn\Bbb Z\right)\right)}{n}\right)^2-x^2}= \pm\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sgn\left(sec\left(n\,tan^{-1}\left(\frac {\pm\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sgn\left(sec\left(n\,tan^{-1}\left(\frac {…}{x}\right)+kn\Bbb Z\right)\right)}{n}\right)^2-x^2}}{x}\right)+kn\Bbb Z\right)\right)}{n}\right)^2-x^2}}$$

Notice the “stable” points of interest at around (x,y) at  ($\infty$,0),(0,0),(.7,0),(0,$\pm$ .41), and (0,$\pm$1.1). There also appear to be 2 asymptotes of $\theta=\pm\frac\pi3\implies y=\pm\sqrt3x$ Here is what the fractal looks like up to n=1000 for the truncated sum. Firstly is a cartesian plot:

[image]

Zoomed in polar plot of “chaotic” section:
[image]

Full fractal:
[image]

The full [polar area](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/PolarArea.aspx) of the fractal from $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$ diverges, but the primitive area formula can be written in terms of [digamma functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function):
$$\mathrm{A=\frac12\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{sgn(sec(m\theta)sgn(sec(n\theta))}{mn}d\theta=\frac{\theta}2\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sgn(sec(n \theta))}n\right)^2}$$

Although there are many types of fractal dimensions, this one probably does not have an easy solution for the dimension. I would like a fractal dimension in [exact form](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactSolution.html) as there is little hope for a closed form solution. Besides this, any interesting information about the fractal itself is appreciated. There is also the possibility of r=r($\theta$) not being a fractal. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The dimension should be the same as the cartesian fractal $$
y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(\sec(n x))}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(\cos(n x))}{n}$$

Comment: @GEdgar In that case, the linked post has that same fractal, but just vertically shifted. However, the polar fractal has a different cartesian equation than the non polar one: $\mathrm{y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sgn(sec(nx))}{n}\ne \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sgn\left(sec\left(n\,tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)+kn\Bbb Z\right)\right)}{n}}$

Comment: The two graphs are certainly not the same.  I merely said they have the same dimension.

Comment: @GEdgar I see thanks. This dimension then depends on the linked question.

Comment: @GEdgar I mean [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859810/fractal-dimension-of-the-function-fx-sum-n-1-infty-frac-mathrmsign-l?noredirect=1&lq=1) question. Thanks for the help.